# ¿Cómo mapear un array sin descripción?

Tags: reactjs

Tengo una duda: estoy tratando de mapear un arreglo.
El arreglo es mas o menos asi:

```
politicas : 
[ 0 : {descripcion: "prueba", id :1}, 
  1:  [
       0:{descripcion: "prueba2", id:2},
       1:{descripcion:"prueba3", id :3}
]
```

Lo estoy tratando de mapear de la siguiente forma:

```
<ul>
  {(() => {
    return this.state.termsandconditions.map((object, keyObject) => {
      return <li key={keyObject}>{object.description}</li>;
    });
  })()}
  <ol>
    {(() => {
      return this.state.termsandconditions.map((object, keyObject) => {
        if (object[keyObject] == '') {
          return <li key={keyObject}>{object.description}</li>;
        }
      });
    })()}
  </ol>
</ul>
```

la primera parte la puedo mapear bien pero en el array hay dentro otro array que no se bien como mapearlo

mi codigo me muestra la primera descripcion y la segunda y tercer descripcion ya no la muestra

Quedo atento a sus comentarios y muchas gracias de antemano

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Espero haber entendido bien, pero creo que necesitas algo como esto:

```js
class TuComponente extends React.Component {
  state = {
    politicas: [
      { descripcion: 'prueba', id: 1 },
      [
        { descripcion: 'prueba2', id: 2 },
        { descripcion: 'prueba3', id: 3 },
      ],
    ],
  };

  renderPolitica = (politica) => {
    return <li key={politica.id}>{politica.descripcion}</li>;
  };

  renderPoliticas = (politicas) => {
    return politicas.map((politica) => {
      if (politica instanceof Array) {
        return <ol>{politica.map(this.renderPolitica)}</ol>;
      } else {
        return this.renderPolitica(politica);
      }
    });
  };

  render() {
    const { politicas } = this.state;
    return <ul>{this.renderPoliticas(politicas)}</ul>;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<TuComponente />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```